# Merge Rows with same value into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written the following query :

```
select distinct
t0.DocDate
,t4.U_SES_VS as 'Value stream'

,case when (t1.ItemCode) = 'WC-QA' then count(t1.itemcode)  else 0 end as 'WC-QA'
,case when  (t1.ItemCode) = 'WC-REC_INSPECTION' then count(t1.itemcode)  else 0 end as 'Inspection'


from ige1 t1 
INNER JOIN OIGE T0 ON T1.DOCENTRY = T0.DOCENTRY 
and few other tables T2,T3,T4,T5 all on Inner Join

Where t1.qty > = t3.qty

group by t0.docdate,t4.u_ses_vs,t1.itemcode
```

I have the Following Output:

```
 **DocDate** |   **Value Stream** | **WC-QA**  | **Inspection**    |
2017-04-14   |   Engineering      |       0    |       0           |
2017-04-14   |   Production       |       14   |       0           |
2017-04-14   |   Quality          |       5    |       0           |
2017-04-14   |   Quality          |       0    |       1           |
```

I want to merge the Quality Row to be in the following format :

```
2017-04-14    |    Quality    |      5     |   1      |
```

how do i do this ?

Comment: I am working with Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select t0.DocDate
       sum(case when t1.ItemCode = 'WC-QA' then 1 else 0 end) as WC_QA,
       sum(case when t1.ItemCode = 'WC-REC_INSPECTION' then 1 else 0 end) as Inspection
from ige1 t1 INNER JOIN
     OIGE T0
     ON T1.DOCENTRY = T0.DOCENTRY 
    and few other tables T2,T3,T4,T5 all on Inner Join
Where t1.qty > = t3.qty
group by t0.docdate;
```

I call this "conditional aggregation"; that is when the `case` goes inside the aggregation function.

Notes:

- `select distinct` is almost never appropriate with `group by`.  That usually indicates a problem.
- `group by` without aggregation functions usually indicates a problem.
- Use the `group by` to define each unique row that you want in the result set.  In this case, you seem to want one row per date.
- Only use single quotes for string and date constants; do not use them for column aliases.

Comment: Thankx a lot . It worked. And thank you for those pointers !!

Answer (score 0):

Take the values from the grouping and use SUM:

```
select 
t0.DocDate
,t4.U_SES_VS as 'Value stream'
,SUM(case when (t1.ItemCode) = 'WC-QA' then count(t1.itemcode)  else 0 end) as 'WC-QA'
,sum(case when  (t1.ItemCode) = 'WC-REC_INSPECTION' then count(t1.itemcode)  else 0 end) as 'Inspection'
from ige1 t1 
INNER JOIN OIGE T0 ON T1.DOCENTRY = T0.DOCENTRY 
and few other tables T2,T3,T4,T5 all on Inner Join
Where t1.qty > = t3.qty
group by t0.docdate,t4.u_ses_vs
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change `Count` to `SUM` and remove `t1.itemcode` in  `group by`.
Remove `distinct` because you have `group by`

```
select 
t0.DocDate
,t4.U_SES_VS as 'Value stream'
,SUM(case when (t1.ItemCode) = 'WC-QA' then 1  else 0 end) as 'WC-QA'
,SUM(case when  (t1.ItemCode) = 'WC-REC_INSPECTION' then 1  else 0 end) as 'Inspection'

from ige1 t1 
INNER JOIN OIGE T0 ON T1.DOCENTRY = T0.DOCENTRY 
and few other tables T2,T3,T4,T5 all on Inner Join
Where t1.qty > = t3.qty
group by t0.docdate,t4.u_ses_vs
```